# Using Regular Expressions to Parse Based on Unique Character Sequence

Tags: python

I'm hoping to get some Python assistance with parsing out a column in a DataFrame that has a unique character sequence.
Each record can have a variable number of parameter name/value pairings.

The only way to determine where each name/value pairing ends is by looking for an equal sign and then finding the most immediate preceding comma. This gets a little tricky as some of the values will continue commas, so using a comma to parse won't always yield clean results.

Example below:

| String |
| --- |
| NAME=TEST,TEST ID=1234,ENTRY DESCR=Verify,ENTRY CLASS=CCD,TRACE NO=124313523,12414,ENTRY DATE=210506 |
| DESCRIPTION=TEST,TEST,TEST |

End Result:

| String1 | String2 | String3 | String4 | String5 | String6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME=TEST | TEST ID=1234 | ENTRY DESCR=Verify | ENTRY CLASS=CCD | TRACE NO=124313523,12414 | ENTRY DATE=210506 |
| DESCRIPTION=TEST,TEST,TEST |  |  |  |  |  |

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If the values can contain comma, how are you supposed to know which commas are delimiters and which are part of the value? Why don't you use a parsable format like JSON? Or use a dictionary instead of a string?

Comment: FWIW I wouldn't do this with a regex... it's a horrible format, but relatively straightforward to write a parser for.

Comment: The delimiter is the comma that immediately precedes the equal sign. I have no control over the format of the input and am left with this to work with, unfortunately. The only way I can think of is RegEx, but definitely open to other methods. The additional nuance of having to identify the correct comma before the parameter name makes it tricky, however.

Answer (score 0):

This can certainly be done with Regexs, but for a quick and dirty parser I would do it manually.

First a test suite:

```py
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "encoded,parsed",
    [
        ("X=Y", {"X": "Y"}),
        ("DESCRIPTION=TEST,TEST,TEST", {"DESCRIPTION": "TEST,TEST,TEST"}),
        (
            "NAME=TEST,TEST ID=1234,ENTRY DESCR=Verify,ENTRY CLASS=CCD,TRACE NO=124313523,12414,ENTRY DATE=210506",
            {
                "NAME": "TEST",
                "TEST ID": "1234",
                "ENTRY DESCR": "Verify",
                "ENTRY CLASS": "CCD",
                "TRACE NO": "124313523,12414",
                "ENTRY DATE": "210506",
            },
        ),
    ],
)
def test_parser(encoded, parsed):
    assert parser(encoded) == parsed
```

You'll need to `pip install pytest` if you don't already have it.

Then a parser:

```py
def parser(encoded: str) -> dict[str, str]:
    parsed = {}
    val = []
    for token in reversed(encoded.split("=")):
        if val:
            *vals, token = token.split(",")
            parsed[token] = ",".join(val)
            val = vals
        else:
            val = token.split(",")
    return parsed
```

This is not a 'proper' parser (i.e. the traditional token, lex, parse) but handles this format.  It works as follows:

- step backwards through all the `something=val` pairs.
- split the val (this is strictly pointless, but see below)
- split `something` at the last comma (using a `*` expression to collect all the other components)
- add a new entry into the parsed dict, joining the val back up again with commas

Note that this would work just as well with `val = [token]`.  But you probably don't want a parser which returns a format which in turn needs parsing.  You probably want it to turn `,` separated values into a list of appropriate types.  Currently you have three types: strs, ints and a datetime.  Thus `"".join(val)` could profitably be replaced with `[convert(x) for x in val]`.  `convert` might look something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
def convert(x: str) -> Union[date, int, str]:
    for candidate in (
        lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%y%m%d").date(),
        lambda x: int(x),
        lambda x: x,
    ):
        try:
            return candidate(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

This would then be used by doing something like this in the parser:

```py
converted = [convert(x) for x in val]
if len(converted) == 1:
    converted = converted[0]
parsed[token] = converted
```

However, this conversion function has a problem---it falsely identifies one number as a date.  How exactly to fix this depends on the input data.  Perhaps the date parsing function can be context-agnostic, and just check for a 6-digit input before parsing (or manually split the str and pass to datetime.date).  Perhaps the decision needs to be made in the parser, based on whether the word "DATE" is in the key.

If you *really* want to use regexs, have a look at negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def parse(s: str) -> dict:
    # Split by "=" and by ","
    raw = [x.split(",") for x in s.split("=")]
    
    # Keys are the last element of each row, besides the last
    keys = [k[-1] for k in raw[:-1]]
    
    # Values are all the elements before the last, shifted by one
    values = [",".join(k[:-1]) for k in raw[1:-1]] + [",".join(raw[-1])]
    
    return dict(zip(keys, values))
```

If we try:

```
s1 = "NAME=TEST,TEST ID=1234,ENTRY DESCR=Verify,ENTRY CLASS=CCD,TRACE NO=124313523,12414,ENTRY DATE=210506"
s2 = "DESCRIPTION=TEST,TEST,TEST"

print(parse(s1))
print(parse(s2))
```

We get:

```
>>> {'NAME': 'TEST',
 'TEST ID': '1234',
 'ENTRY DESCR': 'Verify',
 'ENTRY CLASS': 'CCD',
 'TRACE NO': '124313523,12414',
 'ENTRY DATE': '210506'}
>>> {'DESCRIPTION': 'TEST,TEST,TEST'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, everyone! I wound up figuring a way using RegEx and did this in a two lines of code.

```
s1 = "NAME=TEST,TEST ID=1234,ENTRY DESCR=Verify,ENTRY CLASS=CCD,TRACE NO=124313523,12414,ENTRY DATE=210506"

regex=re.compile(',(?=[^,]+=)')
regex.split(s1)
```